# Calculating averages of groups of data

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I am trying to configure a reporting tool for resource planning. I have one JSON object that contains information about my periods(weeks) and a person's role/experience(numeric) in that period.

I have two persons, Dave and Jim. In period 1(week 1) they are both in the same team (Tango) and in period 2(week 2) only Dave is in a team.

How can I use LINQ to calculate (and return) an average experience value for each team for each period? So the returned values would be:

```
Week 1: 2.5
Week 2: 3
```

My JSON object looks like this:

```
"persons": [
        {
            "id": "974d5090-5cf0-4742-a773-cbc17eaa3362",
            "periods": [
                {
                    "periodName": "Week1",
                    "teamName": "Tango",
                    "roleName": "SoftwareEngineerII",
                    "roleExperience": "2",
                    "id": "cc1f6e14-40f6-4a79-8c66-5f3e773e0929"
                },
                {
                    "periodName": "Week2",
                    "teamName": "Tango",
                    "roleName": "SoftwareEngineerIII",
                    "roleExperience": "3",
                    "id": "bc121b26-b020-4029-8a95-b92cb333bc90"
                }
            ],
            "personName": "Dave"
        },
        {
            "id": "341aeea2-4bf1-4e81-a03e-9bff7babad79",
            "periods": [
                {
                    "periodName": "Week1",
                    "teamName": "Tango",
                    "roleName": "SoftwareEngineerIII",
                    "roleExperience": "3",
                    "id": "db7b642c-4502-4a59-8a32-b5bae5ed5195"
                },
                {
                    "periodName": "Week2",
                    "teamName": "-",
                    "roleName": "-",
                    "roleExperience": "-",
                    "id": "6d9a083b-8762-4a37-a659-e9c8bf5baeb5"
                },

            ],
            "personName": "Jim"
        },
        ...
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to project the data to the different periods and years.  Filter out periods that doesn't have a valid time and group them up so you can take the average.

```
var query = Enumerable.From(data.persons)
    .SelectMany(
        "$.periods",
        "{ periodName: $$.periodName, roleExperience: Number($$.roleExperience) }")
    .Where("!isNaN($.roleExperience)")
    .GroupBy(
        "$.periodName",
        "$.roleExperience",
        "{ Period: $, Average: $$.Average() }")
    .ToArray();
```